# Syntax issues while trying to implement an navbar for Angular 6 project

Tags: css, angular

So I'm trying to follow this tutorial [here](https://www.udemy.com/practical-angular-react-node-airbnb-style-application/learn/v4/t/lecture/10290374?start=75).

I had a bit of an issues with the `.scss` file so I'm just sticking to `.css` because its a lot easier for me to follow. Video number 32 (section 4), minute 3:21, is where I start to get lost.

I try and convert the syntax so it can all work on `.css` and without using anything complicated. Here is the udemy teachers code so far:

```
 @import 'variables';

.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;

  .bwm-search {
    height: 50px;
    width: 300px;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 30px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: $main-color;
    font-weight: 500;


  }

  .nav-item {
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .btn-bwm-search {
    border-color: $main-color;
    color: $main-color;

    &:hover, &:focus, &:active {
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: $main-color !important;
      color: $main-color !important;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }

  .dropdown-item {
    font-size: 14px;

    &:active, &:focus {
      background-color: $main-color;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Here is what I'm trying out:

```
@import '../variables';

.navbar 
{
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;

    bwm-search 
    {
      height: 50px;
      width: 300px;
    }

    .navbar-brand 
    {
      margin-right: 30px;
      font-size: 30px;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      color: red;
      font-weight: 500;
    }

    .nav-item 
    {
      font-size: 14px;
    }

    .btn-bwm-search 
    {
      border-color: red;
      color: red;

      :hover red:focus, red:active
      {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: main-color !important;
        color: main-color !important;
        box-shadow: none;
      }
    }
}
```

Like I said, I'm getting a lot of syntax issues.

I knew how to fix most of them and did but some are still present.

Main-color isn't as clear when it comes to fixing, and it appears as though I'm having some errors with the identifiers.

[Pic of problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWGGO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is invalid; if you are not working with any pre-processor it should be like this:

```
.navbar {
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.navbar bwm-search {
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand {
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.navbar .nav-item {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.navbar .btn-bwm-search {
  border-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.navbar .btn-bwm-search:hover red:focus,
red:active {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: main-color !important;
  color: main-color !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I noticed you left out the import, do you want me to leave it out or....? and i tried using the preprocessor but i didn't know exactly where to place the code in order to make it work. The person in the video used the preprocessor but I couldn't because him and I have two different versions of angular and was hard to figure out where to place that code segment.

Comment: Using the latest version of angular 6, do you know where the preprocessor code snippet will go?

Comment: I think that depends on what you use and if you're building everything with the Angular CLI, maybe this'll help you out: https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-sass-with-the-angular-cli#toc-converting-a-current-app-to-sass

Comment: The thing with variable imports in Angular, is that since you have `ViewEncapsulation` you can't have a *global* file per se; AFAIK you would have to import your variables on all the components you want to use them; unless you turn ViewEncapsulation off; which is not recommended